# Pylint best practices

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

Pylint looks like a good tool for running analysis of Python code.

However, our main objective is to catch any potential bugs and not coding conventions. Enabling all Pylint checks seems to generate a lot of noise. What is the set of Pylint features you use and is effective?

Answer (score 25):

You can block any warnings/errors you don't like, via:

`pylint --disable=error1,error2`

I've blocked the following (description from http://www.logilab.org/card/pylintfeatures):

W0511: Used when a warning note as FIXME or XXX is detected

W0142: Used * or * magic*. Used when a function or method is called using `*args` or `**kwargs` to dispatch arguments. This doesn't improve readability and should be used with care.

W0141: Used builtin function %r. Used when a black listed builtin function is used (see the bad-function option). Usual black listed functions are the ones like map, or filter, where Python offers now some cleaner alternative like list comprehension.

R0912: Too many branches (%s/%s). Used when a function or method has too many branches, making it hard to follow.

R0913: Too many arguments (%s/%s). Used when a function or method takes too many arguments.

R0914: Too many local variables (%s/%s). Used when a function or method has too many local variables.

R0903: Too few public methods (%s/%s). Used when class has too few public methods, so be sure it's really worth it.

W0212: Access to a protected member %s of a client class. Used when a protected member (i.e. class member with a name beginning with an underscore) is access outside the class or a descendant of the class where it's defined.

W0312: Found indentation with %ss instead of %ss. Used when there are some mixed tabs and spaces in a module.

C0111: Missing docstring. Used when a module, function, class or method has no docstring. Some special methods like `__init__` don't necessarily require a docstring.

C0103: Invalid name "%s" (should match %s). Used when the name doesn't match the regular expression associated to its type (constant, variable, class...).

Comment: The description of disabling particular types of message is correct, but I believe some of the specific choices of suppressed errors are controversial. Stuff like "Too many local variables/branches" is a huge red flag.

Comment: The `-d, --disable` option is not a python list with `[]` characters; it is just a comma-delimited list. So not `--disable=[C0111,R0912]`; use `--disable=C0111,R0912`.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"No result matching query"*

Answer (score 13):

To persistently disable warnings and conventions:

1. Create a `~/.pylintrc` file by running `pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc`
2. Edit `~/.pylintrc`
3. Uncomment `disable=` and change that line to `disable=W,C`

Answer (score 9):

[Pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) should serve your purpose well.

Comment: What does it have to do with Pylint? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4395913/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7):

*-E* will only flag what Pylint thinks is an error (i.e., no warnings, no conventions, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Using [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) like:

```
pylint my_file.py | grep -v "^C"
```

Edit :
As mentionned in the question, to remove the conventions advices from pylint output, you remove the lines that start with an uppercase C.

From the [doc of pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/output.html), the output consists in lines that fit the format

```
MESSAGE_TYPE: LINE_NUM:[OBJECT:] MESSAGE
```

and the message type can be:

- [R]efactor for a “good practice” metric violation
- [C]onvention for coding standard violation
- [W]arning for stylistic problems, or minor programming issues
- [E]rror for important programming issues (i.e. most probably bug)
- [F]atal for errors which prevented further processing

Only the first letter is displayed, so you can play with grep to select/remove the level of message type you want.

I didn't use Pylint recently, but I would probably use a parameter inside Pylint to do so.

Comment: What is it supposed to filter out? Can you provide an example? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38899514/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Filter out "C" for *"convention"*? The others are *"refactoring"*, *"warnings"*, *"errors (probable bugs)"*, and *"fatal"* (?).